# Network is Down after setting interface to Promiscuous Mode

Tags: c, sockets, interface, posix

Network always goes down after setting interface to promiscuous mode via:

```
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, if_name);
ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr);
```

Is it possible that the router knows about this attempt and it blocks my connection?

If so, how is it that applications like Wireshark stay on? Is there a way to hide this mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't just set the IFF_PROMISC flag - it also clears all other flags, such as IFF_UP which makes the interface up. Therefore, your code makes the interface go down.

If you only want to change one flag, you can use `SIOCGIFFLAGS` (G for Get) to get the old flags, then edit the one flag you want and set them.